# Handling top 'x' close button click in SDL2 window

Tags: events, sdl-2

There are plenty of questions and answers on pressing the close ('x') button on the **last** existing window in an SDL2 program. In that case, the SDL_QUIT event gets triggered (see https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_EventType) and you can handle the event via that. However, if you have **two or more** windows open, and you press the close button on one of them, which event gets triggered? I cannot find anything on this. I have tried using SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE to catch the event, but that does not seem to work either.

Comment: `event.type==SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event.window.event==SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE`

Comment: Thanks, if you want to add it as an answer, I will accept it, otherwise I will just leave it as-is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short working C++ snippet here below: clicking on the "X" button closes both open windows and quit the application.

```
switch (m_event.type) {

    case SDL_KEYDOWN:

        switch (m_event.key.keysym.sym) {

            case SDLK_m:                 // enter menu state
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                machine->popState();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        break;

    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:

        switch (m_event.window.event) {

            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE:   // exit game
                machine->quit();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        break;

    default:
        // logFileStderr("TutorialState unknown event...\n");
        break;
}
```